# Jupyter notebook connecting only after I interrupt it- how to fix this strange behavior?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I run Jupyter notebook installed in anaconda in WSL with the command "jupyter notebook."
It first gives me:

```
Serving notebooks from local directory: my/directory/ 
Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token= (my token)
Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

but when I paste the link to my browser it keeps loading and never connects...
and then weirdly enough, when I interrupt the terminal by ctrl-c
the link suddenly starts working!

This is what I get after interrupting, and it might be telling something:

```
^C[I 22:53:25.793 NotebookApp] interrupted
Serving notebooks from local directory: /mnt/c/Users/ (MY dir) 
0 active kernels
Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:
http://localhost:8888/?token=
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=
Shutdown this notebook server (y/[n])? No answer for 5s: resuming operation...
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1968, in _confirm_exit
    self.io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(self._restore_sigint_handler)
AttributeError: 'NotebookApp' object has no attribute 'io_loop'
```

I updated both conda and jupyter notebook and the behavior persists.
Why is it acting like this, and what is the fix?